# The game over line isn't working. Why isn't it correctly displaying the games won and lost?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code for a game of 21 or Blackjack. On the final line it won't display the number of games won and number of games lost but I can't figure out how to fix it. Can someone help me correct this? I did this on python 3.6.1

P.S. If there is anything else that can be improved here, feedback would be much appreciated.

```
import random
from random import choice
import time
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
name = str(input("Welcome to " + Fore.YELLOW + "21" + Style.RESET_ALL + "! I'll be your dealer. \nWhat's your name?"))
instructions=""
while instructions!="N" and instructions!="Y":
  instructions=str(input("Would you like to see the Instructions? Y/N"))
  if instructions!="N" and instructions!="Y":
    print("That is not a valid answer.")
  else:
    time.sleep(1)
if instructions=="Y":
  print(Fore.GREEN + "Instructions:" + Style.RESET_ALL + "\nYour objective is to get as close as you can to " + Fore.YELLOW + "21" + Style.RESET_ALL + ".\n>Each round, you will be dealt two standard cards. You must add these and the person with the closest total wins. \n>You will choose whether to 'hit' or 'miss' every round. If you hit, you get dealt another card. However, be careful as going over " + Fore.YELLOW + "21 " + Style.RESET_ALL + "causes you to bust and lose! \n>Picture cards are worth 10 points each.\n>Aces are 1 or 11, randomly.")
  time.sleep(1)
else:
  print("")
rounds=int(input("How many rounds do you want to play " + name + "?"))
gamesLost=0
gamesWon=0
def twentyone():
  roun=0
  for i in range(0,rounds):
    gamesLost=0
    gamesWon=0
    roun+=1
    print("Round " + str(roun))
    cards=['Ace','Ace','Ace','Ace','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','4','4','4','4','5','5','5','5','6','6','6','6','7','7','7','7','8','8','8','8','9','9','9','9','10','10','10','10','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Queen','Queen','Queen','Queen','King','King','King','King']
    cardVal = {'Ace':random.randint(1,11),'King':10,'Queen':10,'Jack':10,'10':10,'9':9,'8':8,'7':7,'6':6,'5':5,'4':4,'3':3,'2':2}
    card1=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(card1)
    card2=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(card2)
    hands=(str(card1) + ", " + str(card2))
    playerHand = cardVal[card1]+cardVal[card2]
    print("Your hand is " + hands + ". Your hand is worth " + str(playerHand) + ".")
    hit=""
    while hit!="H" and hit!="S" and hit!="h" and hit!="s":
      hit=str(input("Do you want to hit (H) or stay (S)?"))
      if hit!="H" and hit!="S" and hit!="h" and hit!="s":
        print("That is not a valid answer.")
      else:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    while hit=="H" or hit=="h":
      card=random.choice(cards)
      cards.remove(card)
      playerHand+=cardVal[card]
      hands=(hands + ", " + str(card))
      print("Your hand is " + hands + ". Your hand is worth " + str(playerHand) + ".")
      if playerHand>21:
        break
      else:
        time.sleep(0.01)
      hit=str(input("Do you want to hit (H) or stay (S)?"))
    if playerHand>21:
      print("Sorry, you bust!")
      gamesLost+=1
      i+=1
    else:
      time.sleep(0.01)
    cpuCard1=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(cpuCard1)
    cpuCard2=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(cpuCard2)
    handsCPU=(str(cpuCard1) + ", " + str(cpuCard2))
    computerHand=cardVal[cpuCard1]+cardVal[cpuCard2]
    while computerHand<17:
      if computerHand<17:
        cpuCard=random.choice(cards)
        cards.remove(cpuCard)
        computerHand+=cardVal[cpuCard]
        handsCPU=(handsCPU + ", " + str(cpuCard))
      else:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    if computerHand>21:
      print("I'm bust! You win.")
      gamesWon+=1
      i+=1
    elif computerHand>playerHand:
      print("My hand is " + str(handsCPU) + ". It is worth " + str(computerHand) + ". You lose.")
      gamesLost+=1
      i+=1
    else:
      print("My hand is " + str(handsCPU) + ". It is worth " + str(computerHand) + ". You win.")
      gamesLost+=1
      i+=1
twentyone()
print("\nGame Over!")
print("You won " + str(gamesWon) + " and lost " + str(gamesLost) + ".")
again=str(input("Do you want to go again? Y/N"))
if again=="Y":
  rounds=int(input("How many rounds do you want to play " + name + "?"))
  twentyone()
elif again=="N":
  print("Have a nice day.")
else:
  print("Have a nice day.")
```

Comment: Please make an effort to reduce the code you include to the minimum amount required to reproduce the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't test it myself since I don't have all modules. But I assume your issue is that the line print says you won and lost 0 games every time.

It looks like you're resetting your game-counters with every new game:

```
for i in range(0,rounds):
    gamesLost=0
    gamesWon=0
```

You play one game, record games won and lost and then reset both to 0 for the next game when the loop starts over. Since you're also initialising both counters just before the loop - but also outside the def - it should work if you remove both lines. Or you can move the lines before the loop and maybe remove the other copy if it is redundant. Defining the counters inside your function is the better approach, though.